# HBase Kerberos SaslException: GSS initiate failed (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)

Tags: kerberos, centos6.5, hbase

I am trying to set up Kerberos authentication for HBase using this http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/security.html documentation and have very little progress so far.

HBase 1.1.1 from Apache without any Cloudera influences. Host machine is running under Centos 6.5.

I've already set up Kerberos KDC and client after following instruction https://gist.github.com/ashrithr/4767927948eca70845db 
KDC is located on the same machine as HBase I'm trying to secure.

All-in-all, here's current environment state:
keytab file is here /opt/hbase.keytab

hbase-site.xml contents

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///opt/hbase-data/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/opt/hbase-data/zookeeper</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenProvider</value>
  </property>


  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.keytab.file</name>
    <value>/opt/hbase.keytab</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>hbase/_HOST@XXX.MYCOMPANY.COM</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>hbase/_HOST@XXX.MYCOMPANY.COM</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.keytab.file</name>
    <value>/opt/hbase.keytab</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

It's a pseudo-distributed mode and I didn't bother with undelying HDFS to keep things as simple as possible.

However when I start hbase with ./start-hbase command I get following error in *regionserver*.log

```
2015-10-20 17:33:18,068 INFO  [regionserver/xxx.mycompany.com/172.24.4.60:16201] regionserver.HRegionServer: reportForDuty to master=xxx.mycompany.com,16000,1445349909162 with port=16201, startcode=1445349910087 2015-10-20 17:33:18,071 WARN  [regionserver/xxx.mycompany.com/172.24.4.60:16201] ipc.AbstractRpcClient: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)] 2015-10-20 17:33:18,071 FATAL [regionserver/xxx.mycompany.com/172.24.4.60:16201] ipc.AbstractRpcClient: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'. javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:609)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$600(RpcClientImpl.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:735)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:732)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:732)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:885)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:854)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.RegionServerStatusProtos$RegionServerStatusService$BlockingStub.regionServerStartup(RegionServerStatusProtos.java:8982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.reportForDuty(HRegionServer.java:2260)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:893)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
        ... 18 more 2015-10-20 17:33:18,072 WARN  [regionserver/xxx.mycompany.com/172.24.4.60:16201] regionserver.HRegionServer: error telling master we are up com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Could not set up IO Streams to xxx.mycompany.com/172.24.4.60:16000
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.RegionServerStatusProtos$RegionServerStatusService$BlockingStub.regionServerStartup(RegionServerStatusProtos.java:8982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.reportForDuty(HRegionServer.java:2260)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:893)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not set up IO Streams to xxx.mycompany.com/172.24.4.60:16000
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:777)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:885)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:854)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
        ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$1.run(RpcClientImpl.java:677)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(RpcClientImpl.java:635)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:743)
        ... 9 more Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:609)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$600(RpcClientImpl.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:735)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:732)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:732)
        ... 9 more Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
        ... 18 more 2015-10-20 17:33:18,073 WARN  [regionserver/xxx.mycompany.com/172.24.4.60:16201] regionserver.HRegionServer: reportForDuty failed; sleeping and then retrying.
```

I presume Kerberos works because I can obtain

```
$ klist -ekt hbase.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:hbase.keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   3 10/19/15 17:11:42 hbase/xxx.mycompany.com@XXX.MYCOMPANY.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   3 10/19/15 17:11:42 hbase/xxx.mycompany.com@XXX.MYCOMPANY.COM (des3-cbc-sha1)
   3 10/19/15 17:11:42 hbase/xxx.mycompany.com@XXX.MYCOMPANY.COM (des-cbc-crc)



$ kinit -kt /opt/hbase.keytab hbase/xxx.mycompany.com@XXX.MYCOMPANY.COM
[userx1@gms-01 logs]$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_2369
Default principal: hbase/xxx.mycompany.com@XXX.MYCOMPANY.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
10/20/15 17:49:32  10/21/15 03:49:32  krbtgt/XXX.MYCOMPANY.COM@XXX.MYCOMPANY.COM
        renew until 10/27/15 16:49:32
```

hbase shell produces the same exception as provided above when trying to run status (or whatever) command

If anyone has any suggestions or advices please let me know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and got it resolved by starting region server separately. Make sure when you are starting daemons, you have valid Kerberos TGT.